# Serenity + Sauce Lab: How to fix Authentication Error

Tags: serenity-bdd, saucelabs

I need some help with authentication on sauce lab. I want to run serenity java selenium test on sauce lab. I registered on Sauce Lab and I get username and authentication key.

I set in serenity property file:

```
saucelabs.url=http://d.stanisXXXXX:XXXXX-4797@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub
saucelabs.user.id=d.stanisXXXXX
saucelabs.access.key=XXXXX-4797

saucelabs.target.platform=XP
saucelabs.driver.version=26
```

And I run tests. I get authentication error:

```
Caused by: net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: Could not 
instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver (Unable to parse remote response: 
Misconfigured -- Sauce Labs Authentication Error.
You used username 'd.stanisXXXXX' and access key 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX- 
XXXXeefa4797' to authenticate, which are not valid Sauce Labs credentials.
...Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Unable to determine 
type from: M. Last 1 characters read: M
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your values have some duplication in them. Can you try setting your values like this?

```
saucelabs.url=http://d.stanisXXXXX:XXXXX-4797@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub
saucelabs.user.id=d.stanisXXXXX
saucelabs.access.key=XXXXX-4797
```

Also Sauce [no longer supports using Windows XP](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=70074721) so you will have to update that to Windows 7 or later. Happy Testing!

Comment: Thanks for reply! Yes, I set values properly, it was my mistake when I typed post here, I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Saucelab technical support replied on my question. The thing is that my account is in EU DC. Hence the URL endpoint where I run the tests should be:

String URL = "https://" + USERNAME + ":" + ACCESS_KEY + "@ondemand.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub";

Problem is solved.

And yes, XP is not supported anymore.